# Displaying single pane alert in javafx

Tags: javafx, alert

I am using the following code to show an error alert :

```
 Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setContentText(resourceBundle.getString("loginError"));
            alert.showAndWait();
```

[image]

This alert looks a little weird to me as there are two panes the top one just showing Error and a cross button and the bottom one showing the text `incorrect username or password`
Is there some way to get rid of the top pane?
As the header pane already showing Error and cross button I don't see the reason for the next pane to show Error and a red cross button

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: `alert.setHeaderText(null);`   https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Comment: @Sedrick Cool that works pretty well. But I still see that red cross is there a way to remove that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the header try,

```
alert.setHeaderText(null);
```

To remove the icon try,

```
alert.setGraphic(null);
```

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("Error");
alert.setContentText("Incorrect Username or Password");
alert.setHeaderText(null);
alert.setGraphic(null);
alert.showAndWait();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
```

This will remove the header alert.